# Customising the wingpanel in juno? like adding blur?

Tags: wingpanel, release-juno, dconf

I have dconf editor but everything is changed in juno. so we cant edit the wingpanels opacity there. if we can, how? i have recently arrived at linux environment so please help me out a bit. thanks

Comment: You just "arrived" to the linux environment but also you have some background to define that all changed with Juno. Also you don't provide any screenshot or detailes report of what you did in the past and what you expect tp happen now. We can't read minds ....yet. AFAIK the "thing" you are looking for is in the theme

Comment: I really am new to Linux as i installed eos for the first time last month and that to Juno is my first attempt to Linux. Of course I searched the net before coming here and saw tutorials but they are outdated and Juno is not the same anymore. As for things I have done.......nothing its a fresh install so didn't think it was necessary but maybe it was ignorance so I will still post but I think it will same as any Juno stock image you see online. Any way thanks for the advice but what do i have to change in the themes folder?can you specify?

Comment: he answered for you.. but like he said be carefull if you don't know css ... at least make a copy of the original file https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17266/14940. This is the link to the github page where is being developed https://github.com/elementary/stylesheet/blob/master/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css

Comment: And here you can ask/request something to the Dev team https://github.com/elementary/stylesheet/issues. Next time don't assume is all the same, the difference with Linux and other OS's is that not any Linux is the same you can choose not to install something that others did that caused a problem... etc. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

you can modify that panel in apps.css

sudo io.elementary.code /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css

search `/*********
        * Panel *
        ********/`and modify what you want to change Colors, transparency. # 000 is color and 0.0 is transparency.
I recommend you to be very careful since you can break something, also so that you know about how to modify things look for hex codes for colors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new `dconf-editor` location you're looking for is `/io/elementary/desktop/wingpanel`

Uncheck `use-transparency`

[image]

Comment: Oh right thanks that helped me out! Cheers. Also Is there any way to change the opacity according to our need like before?

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure what the new keys are to add to the command `gsettings set io.elementary.desktop.wingpanel`. I will update my answer if I find out. Like you said, the old keys don't work.